# Conflicting types for function 'read'

Tags: c

```
bool read(const char* format, void* address)
```

What I have tried:

```
bool readTest(const char* format, void* address)
```

I keep getting a Conflicting types for 'read' prompt with regards to `bool read`, what does this mean?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're receiving? Have you tried naming the function something else?

Comment: The error appears next to this line ```bool read(const char* format, void* address)```

Comment: The message is Conflicting types of 'read', I tried inserting ```bool readtest(const char* format, void* address)``` after checking out some online forums, but the problem manifested, so I assume I'm on the wrong path.

Comment: `read` is a standard function. Rename your `read` function to `myRead` or something similar and it should work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], emphasis on __Minimal__.

Comment: I've copied your code, renamed the read function (every occurance), it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks for the advice, it works fine right now. However, I'm still curious, why doesn't ```readTest``` work though?

Comment: On windows 7 machine your program compiles and runs as expected

Comment: `readTest` should be fine, as long as you fixed everywhere it was used. Without an example using `readTest` that fails and the copy/pasted compile error it's impossible to guess. I also had no trouble compiling this on a couple of platforms with different compilers.  Are you using something like Turbo C?

Comment: @EvelynWein so with `myRead` it works but with `readTest` it doesn't?

Comment: I'm using Xcode to run my programs, it's a bit different from Windows it seems. Sometimes the output is not shown on Xcode, but executable on Win.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yup, that's right.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], I suspect that you have a "special" definition of `bool` especially a different one in the two shown lines. That depends heavily on included header, their order and other definitions. (Sorry, I see that you already did react on practically the same comment. Well done. But now please a little less stress on "minimal" and a little more on "reproducable".)

Comment: Do you have some macro like `#define readTest read` somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: you invade the POSIX namespace of identifiers. `read` is a function declared in `<unistd.h>` as `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`.

The proper fix is to avoid reserved identifiers. Simply rename your function.